# Unable to find out the error in the mongo DB union with query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo db, here I am trying to convert mysql query to mongo db query.

Here, I have to do just union of some fields from 2 collections in mongodb without any conditions. No common fields are present in both collections. Below mentioned my query, I am able to see output of only "account_id","account_name" and concatination. I am unable to see output of which I am trying to project inside union query is not showing
in output. Can anyone please help me on this.

```
db.accounts.aggregate(
        {
          "$unionWith": {
            "coll": "parent_child", "pipeline": [
              {
                "$project": {
                  "child_id":"$CHILD_ID",
                  "name":"$NAME"
              }
            }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$project":{
            "account_id":"$ACCOUNT_ID",
            "name":"$ACCOUNT_NAME"
          }
        }
      )
```

For your understanding, I am posting mysql query.

```
select p.CHILD_ID as account_id,p.NAME as name from parent_child p union select a.ACCOUNT_ID as account_id,a.ACCOUNT_NAME as name from account a
```

Providing sample records of both collections:

```
1.accounts

[{account_id:1,
  name:"abc"},
  {account_id:2,
   name:"test"}]

2. parent_child:

[{CHILD_ID:23
  NAME:"test child"},
 [CHILD_ID:34,
  NAME:"test1]}
```

Expected Output:

```
[{account_id:1,
  name:"abc"},
 {account_id:2,
  name:"test"},
 {account_id:21,
  name:"test child"},
 {account_id:34,
  name:"test2"}]
```

Comment: Move the `$project` stage before the `$unionWith` stage. The `$project` only shows the fields that are specified with it.

Comment: I want to display fields which are present in $unionWith. Is that possible?

Comment: I need to get specified records from both collections. There is no common field and there is no condition Is that possible?

Comment: Then, just remove the `$project` stage and try.

Comment: which project I have to remove main one inside union query? then How do I have to fetch and project specified records from both collections? for now in project I am able to see account_id and name

Comment: You can change the `$project` stage to `$addFields` stage - the second stage with the `account_id`, .... Please ignore my earlier comment about removing the stage.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I am not getting completely..

Comment: You can include sample input documents and also a sample expected output in your post (use the "edit").

Comment: I have added sample input documents and expected output also. I need to project mentioned fields from both collections. These collections don't have any relation or conditions.

Comment: The sample documents need to be MongoDB documents or JSON. Also, your aggregation code syntax is not correct.

Comment: You need to show sample data as the proper document format, for example: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/document/ . For multiple documents include them in an array:  `[ { ... }, { ... }, ...  ]`.

Comment: I have added sample data in the form of json and changed the query too. both tables have same type of records(data type) it doesn't have any common field or any conditions. just need to fetch those columns from two collections and try to project mentioned fields in view in one query

Comment: Your aggregation query has **syntax errors**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it can be done, but it is not recommended, as it groups all the documents from two collections into one big document:

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 0,
      accounts: {$push: {account_id: "$account_id", name: "$name"}}
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "parent_child",
      let: {},
      pipeline: [
        {$project: {account_id: "$CHILD_ID", name: "$NAME", _id: 0}}
      ],
      as: "parent_child"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      res: {$concatArrays: ["$accounts", "$parent_child"]},
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZVCd7__zMvx)